# Strange CASE WHEN case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1 (X64) 
    Apr  2 2010 15:48:46 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Fields: FIRSTNAME, DOB (datetime)

[DOB Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d05Ag.png)

Table:

```
FARHAN                     1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
DAWOOD                     2004-04-22 00:00:00.000
```

First query:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, [DOB]) = CONVERT(DATE, '1900-01-01') 
THEN '' ELSE CONVERT(DATE, [DOB]) END AS 'DOB'
```

Result:

```
FARHAN                     1900-01-01
DAWOOD                     2004-04-22
```

Second query:

```
SELECT FIRSTNAME, CASE WHEN CONVERT(DATE, [DOB]) = CONVERT(DATE, '1900-01-01') 
THEN '' ELSE CONVERT (VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATE, [DOB])) END AS 'DOB'
```

Result:

```
FARHAN           
DAWOOD                     2004-04-22
```

Could someone please, did the first query process the ELSE part? Why this difference?

Comment: Why do you have the `= CONVERT(DATE, '1900-01-01')` instead of just `= '1900-01-01'` ?
Also if your column is Datetime and it always holds the time `00:00:00.000` there is no need to convert it to date to begin with - you can use `WHEN [DOB] = '1900-01-01'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could someone please, did the first query process the ELSE part? Why
>   this difference?

No, the first query does not process ELSE, it just shows you `''` casted to `date`.

Since you use `case` and the result of case expression is of one definite type. But you used `char` type (`''`) and `date` type in the same `case`, so one of the types should be converted to other, in your case `char` is converted to `date` according to [Data Type Precedence](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309(v=sql.110).aspx)